# Optimal Buffer Size Back and Forth Communication? (Sockets)

Tags: java, python, sockets, buffer

so this is basically my situation.

I have the server and client both connected and running. The way it works is the server sends information to the client, then WAITS until it receives a response from the client, then the server sends information once again to the client, and this process repeats again and again.
This means they are basically just communicating back in forth. The data they are sending is volatile, sometimes it's large, others small. Needless to say even if it is very small I still flush it out, because the other cannot perform until it receives it.

I was wondering if I should use smaller or larger buffer sizes for sending/receiving. This is because I feel like it may be a waste if I have a huge buffer size like 65536, then flush out something as small as "Hello", but then again sometimes the data can be as large as 100 megabytes.

Anybody have any clue on what I should do?

Is it waste to have a large buffer size if I flush out a small amount of data?

Is there a way to adjust buffer size depending on the data being sent?

Thanks! I appreciate all/any responses.